# recursive directory iterator step-by-step delete problem

Tags: c++

1)File shape

```
C:\\FTP\\2\\3\\99\\100  There's a txt in 99.
C:\\FTP\\2\\5\\11\\
C:\\FTP\\2\\5\\23\\.txt
C:\\FTP\\2\\.txt
```

2)Code

```
void OldDirectoryCleaner::CleanOldFilesRecursive(boost::filesystem::path TopPath)
{
try
{
    LogS << "Scanning " << TopPath.generic_string() << " >> ";
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(TopPath))
    {
        boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator PathIter{ TopPath };

        while (PathIter != boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{} && *PathIter !=TopPath)
        {
            boost::filesystem::path RemovePath = boost::filesystem::path(*PathIter);
            bool RemoveSuccess = false;
            try
            {
                if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(PathIter->status()))
                {
                    if (boost::filesystem::is_empty(*PathIter))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            LogS << " Deleting empty old folder " << RemovePath.generic_string();
                            boost::filesystem::remove(RemovePath);
                            RemoveSuccess = true;
                            LogS << "Success. ";                        
                        }
                        catch (...)
                        {
                            LogS << "Error. ";
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (...) {}

            if (!RemoveSuccess)
            {
                PathIter++;                                                 
            }

            else 
            {   
                boost::filesystem::path RemovePath = boost::filesystem::path(*PathIter);
                PathIter = boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{ RemovePath.parent_path() };     
                boost::filesystem::path x = RemovePath.parent_path();

            }
```

3) output steps

```
RemovePath  C:\\FTP\\2  
RemovePath  C:\\FTP\\2\\3
RemovePath  C:\\FTP\\2\\3\\99
RemovePath  C:\\FTP\\2\\3\\99\\100 deleted.
RemovePath  C:\\FTP\\2\\3\\99\\.txt" } after this It's getting out of the loop.
```

why not check and delete other empty files?

Comment: It seems like you've posted a similar question [_here_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212620/recursive-directory-iterator-delete-consecutive-empyt-files)?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to familiarise yourself with the site by taking _[the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)_, reading up on _[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_, and understanding _[how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS i forget the editing.sorry.